# C++ pointer casting when passing pointer as parameter to reference

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-cast

I'm curious, is:

```
bool State::operator<(const State* S)
{
  return this->operator<(*dynamic_cast<const State *>(S));
}
```

exactly the same as:

```
bool State::operator<(const State* S)
{
  return this->operator<(*(S));
}
```

For reference the `this->operator<` being called is:

```
bool State::operator<(const State& S)
{
  return this->reward < S.reward ? true : false;
}
```

Which one is more "correct" and type safe / secure to use or, is there any actual difference ?

Comment: I assume you mean `*dynamic_cast<const State *>(S)` in your first example?  Otherwise it is an infinite loop.

Comment: What happens if the `dynamic_cast` fails?

Comment: Als: How could it possibly fail if it casting from the compile-time type to itself?

Comment: @Nemo: And that is the reason it is not needed in first place :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the first one casts the pointer to itself, which doesn't really do anything, and then calls `const State*` overload, which results in an infinite loop. You don't need `dynamic_cast` until you need to downcast at runtime — there is no downcasting here, so

```
return this->operator<(*S);
```

is the only thing to do.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me lots of future trouble !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a typo and you mean to compare this:

```
*dynamic_cast<const State *>(s)
```

...to this:

```
*s
```

...where s has compile-time type `const State *`, there is no difference at all.

It is conceivable that the former could be slightly slower if your compiler does not notice that they are compile-time equivalent.

I would avoid the former on the grounds that anybody reading it will wonder what you are thinking.

Comment: No it wasn't a typo, I completely forgot to make it a pointer. LoL, and it compiled fine.